# Play movie from Windows Media to a DLNA TV: "failed to retrieve media information from media server"

Tags: windows-7, video, windows-media-player, video-streaming, dlna

I have three movie files in my Windows Media Player library. All three of them play fine on the computer. If I choose "Play To" and select my Sony Bravia TV, one of them works fine, but the other two always give the same error: "failed to retrieve media information from media server".

What's the problem here? How do I fix it?

Comment: First point of failure would be the container format.  What's the extensions of the files that won't play?

Comment: One's AVI, the other is MKV. I haven't checked which codecs are used inside because I assumed it gets decoded on the PC anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time when I run into that... it's because the codec used to encode the video isn't compatible with the player.  Just because the computer can play it... doesn't mean the TV knows how to decode it.

Comment: So DLNA sends the raw file then? I kind of thought it gets decoded on the computer.

Comment: Nope... the "Renderer" is the device responsible for both displaying the video and decoding the stream.

Comment: Presumably there are DLNA servers that transcode on the fly then? I'll search around. Thanks!

Comment: Actually... most players won't fully transcode on the fly if the device says it supports one of the many "wrapper" formats like "AVI".  (kinda dumb... as AVI can be just about anything)

Comment: Gah, that's pretty fricken dumb if you ask me...

Comment: @romkyns - well, that's the world of video file formats! Playback compatibility across devices has always been a sticking point for video. Try using a converter program on the files that won't play, and convert them to a format that works on the TV.