# Windows DLNA play-to client

Tags: windows, dlna

I have a fairly recent Samsung TV that supports DLNA and I am able to make it play video for example from my phone (using an app), which is very cool and awesome.

However having to use my phone can be a bit cumbersome compared to, say, a laptop.

Does anyone know of a Windows based DLNA client that supports the ability to 'command' a DLNA receiver to play a video over the protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Media Player in Windows (7+ anyway) supports DLNA.  You can use the "Play To" function to send video to DLNA receivers.

From [Using the Play To feature to stream media](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/using-the-play-to-feature-to-stream-media):

> You can use the Play To feature to stream video, music, or picture files stored on your computer to a separate playback device on your home network. That device could be another computer, TV, or stereo connected to your network.

Also, maybe take a peek at this related SU question, just in case: [Play movie from Windows Media to a DLNA TV: “failed to retrieve media information from media server”](https://superuser.com/questions/374567/play-movie-from-windows-media-to-a-dlna-tv-failed-to-retrieve-media-informatio)

Comment: Regrettably this is indeed a huge gap. Most 'use cases' industry thought of focus around a mobile phone as „controller“. I had also done a lot of research, i.e. MediaMonkey lacks this feature, thus I also have to use Windows Media Player :-/